# hi! .sort method on array with objects not working, any ideas why is that?

Tags: javascript, sorting

```
const speciesArray = [ {speciesName:'shark', numTeeth:50}, {speciesName:'dog', numTeeth:42}, 
{speciesName:'alligator', numTeeth:80}, {speciesName:'human', numTeeth:32}];
 
 const sortSpeciesByTeeth = arr => {arr.sort(item=>{
     item.numTeeth;
     })
        return arr
     }
    console.log(sortSpeciesByTeeth(speciesArray))
 The outcome it produces: undefined. 
 The outcome expected : [ { speciesName: 'human', numTeeth: 32 },
  { speciesName: 'dog', numTeeth: 42 },
  { speciesName: 'shark', numTeeth: 50 },
  { speciesName: 'alligator', numTeeth: 80 } ]
```

Because .sort() method by default sorts nambers with te asending order I didnt use any compare
function
yet it dosent work so propably should but I dont see why. Thanks for any suggestions

Ok, it finally works:

````
{speciesName:'dog', numTeeth:42}, 
{speciesName:'alligator', numTeeth:80}, 
{speciesName:'human', numTeeth:32}];

 function sortSpeciesByTeeth(array) {let sorted = array.sort((a,b)=>
     a.numTeeth - b.numTeeth
     )
        return sorted
     }
    console.log(sortSpeciesByTeeth(speciesArray))```
Thanks for your help guys
````

Comment: What’s telling you the output it produces is `undefined`? I see an array (written by your `console.log`). If it’s an automated grader of some kind, you should look carefully at how it wants you to produce a result. As for creating a correct comparison function to pass to `arr.sort()`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort#Description. (Hint: your comparison function should take *two* arguments, and it should return a value.)

Comment: hi, yes sorry, it actually does produce an array. When i copied the code i put accidently 'return arr' ot of the .sort function parentheses. But it still is not sorting the way i was expecting it. here it is: [ { speciesName: 'shark', numTeeth: 50 },
  { speciesName: 'dog', numTeeth: 42 },
  { speciesName: 'alligator', numTeeth: 80 },
  { speciesName: 'human', numTeeth: 32 } ]. t

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```js
const speciesArray = [{ speciesName: 'shark', numTeeth: 50 }, { speciesName: 'dog', numTeeth: 42 },
{ speciesName: 'alligator', numTeeth: 80 }, { speciesName: 'human', numTeeth: 32 }];

function sortSpeciesByTeeth(input) {
    let sortedArray = input.sort((a, b) => (a.numTeeth > b.numTeeth) ? 1 : -1)
    return sortedArray
}

console.log(sortSpeciesByTeeth(speciesArray))
```